# Deserailizing xml to C# list is empty?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, poco

all deserialization works except for the lists:

(resdes is a list)

```
public class SearchResponse
{
    // ELEMENTS
    [XmlElement("ResDes")]
    public ResDes resdes { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Return")]
    public Return returns { get; set; }

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public SearchResponse()
    {}
}
```

this works:

```
 <Return>
  <test>0010000725</test> 
  </Return>


    public class Return 
{

    // ELEMENTS
    [XmlElement("test")]
    public Test test{ get; set; }

 }
```

but the list of items doesn't work it deserailizes into null

```
<ResDes >
 <item>  
     <PoBox />    
     <City1>South Korea</City1>      
     <Country>SK</Country>    
 </item>   
</ResDes >


 public class ResDes 
{
    // ELEMENTS
    [XmlArrayItem("item")]
    public List<ResDesItem> ResDesItem { get; set; }

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public ResDes ()
    { }
}
```

Resdesitem class:

```
 [DataContract()]
public class ResDesItem
{

    [XmlElement("PoBox")]
    public PoBox PoBox { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("City1")]
    public City1 City1 { get; set; }


    [XmlElement("Country")]
    public EtResultDetAdritemCountry EtResultDetAdritemCountry { get; set; }

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public ResDesItem()
    { }
}
```

Comment: Did you try marking the ResDesItem class with the `[Serializable]` attribute?

Comment: hi, I am currently developing for the phone platform, so I used its equivlnt [DataContract()], but it still is empty

Comment: Where is the `ResDesItem` class?  Can you paste that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: Do not forget to add [DataMember] on each property or member of class **

If you want to do this with DataContract way, use it in the following manner:

```
[DataContract]
[XmlRoot("item")]
[XmlType]
public class ResDesItem
{
    [XmlElement("PoBox")]
    [DataMember]
    public string PoBox { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("City1")]
    [DataMember]
    public string City1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Country")]
    [DataMember]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[DataContract]
[XmlRoot("ResDes")]
[XmlType]
public class ResDes
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    [DataMember]
    public List<ResDesItem> ResDesItem { get; set; }
}
```

rest is same as prev answer by me.

Comment: Why did you answer twice?

Comment: If someone wants to do serialization using [DataContract] second answer will work and if someone wants it with [Serializable] Answer 1 will work. So, I've added the separate answer for it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Do I need to remove any answer?

Comment: hi, I did try this code however im getting exceptions since I want to deserialize all of the xml, so changing it into a stream and trying to deserialize the response soap headers gives exceptions, however Im guessing your answer will work, s thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two classes as:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("ResDes")]
[XmlType]
public class ResDes
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<ResDesItem> ResDesItem { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("item")]
[XmlType]
public class ResDesItem
{
    [XmlElement("PoBox")]
    public string PoBox { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("City1")]
    public string City1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the following code to deserialize it, as:

```
        XmlSerializer xmlReq = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResDes));
        string xml = @"<ResDes> <item><PoBox/><City1>South Korea</City1><Country>SK</Country> </item></ResDes>";

        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(xml));
        var resposnseXml = (ResDes)xmlReq.Deserialize(stream);
```

Comment: hi Mahesh, I did try the above code, however instead of using Serializable attribute I had to use DataContract, since its only available in windows phone, but still doesn't work